# Only access files through ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

Hey I'm wondering if there is a way to only view your files when using ajax. For example
I have ajax set up etc and I made an request but anyone could just figure out my folder structure and go to my php file and anything could happen and I want to throw them an 404 if they try to access that file. I haven't tried anything because I don't have the smallest clue.
Do you need to use .htaccess?

I have tried to search for this on the internet I couldn't find anything so if there is another post similar to this let me know and give me a link thank you.

Comment: I know you said you haven't tried anything, but here's the problem: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: @ArtursLapins It would be very wise to first educate yourself on the topic AJAX, and what it exactly does. The main perspective is, and this is in general. If the file you are trying to access is retrievable by the browser (or any other protocol that allows it, in this case http/https), it can be retrieved using a method called AJAX.

Comment: agreed with dbf above you need first to understand what AJAX is, also try using additional headers or information passed along with request..

Comment: I don't see why DV and VC this. OP has a question that surely has bothered many people, including me. Even though this may seem just stupid or virtually impossible for a seasoned developer, he should at least have an answer of why this is not technically feasible.

Answer (score 1):

Not an easy thing to do.

Ajax, like any other HTTP access, is made through a request. Normal requests are done with the `GET` method, just like there's a `GET` Ajax request method.

I faced a situation as yours not too long and my solution, even though far from perfect, is this:

1. Make all Ajax calls in your application use the `POST` method;
2. Add this to a file which you `include`/`require` in the beginning of each PHP that should be fetched through Ajax:

   ```
   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
       header('Location: /404page.php'); //The / represents the site root
       exit;
   }
   ```

This way, people trying to open your pages directly  will be redirected to a 404 page.

Of course, one can easily fake a POST request header. You could also add a POST parameter to each Ajax call, but one that can fake a header can easily fake the POSTed data as well.

Just do strong server-side validation to make sure that the user has permission to see the page and that all data that it should receive is there and is valid. If someone messes around with request headers and sees ugly pages outside of your application, it's not your problem after all.